# Prove Metric Topology is a Topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have this propostion:

"Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Then, $\tau_ = \{A \subseteq X; \forall x \in A, \exists \epsilon_x; B^d_{\epsilon_x}(x) \subseteq A\}$ is a topology in $X$ called metric topology associated with $d$."

Note that the $B^d_{\epsilon_x}(x)$ is the ball of radius $\epsilon_x$ and center $x$ with the metric $d$.

I was trying to prove this sentence, i mean, prove that the given set is a topology, and I managed all the profs, but i can't get why $X \in \tau_d$. I mean, imagine if $X$ is an interval, like $[0,1]$, and i pike $x = 1$, so, $\forall \epsilon_x > 0$, $B^d_{\epsilon_x}(x) \subseteq X$ is false.

I can't get why I'm having trouble with this, i guess I'm missing some hypothesis or maybe just allucinating. All help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: The problem you're having is that you're thinking of $X=[0, 1]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. But as a metric space it doesn't have anything laying 'outside' it. So an open ball centred at $1$ would still be a subset of $X$ and would look something like $(1-e_1, 1]$.

Comment: Note that $B^d_{\epsilon_x}(x)$ is the 'open' ball of radius $\epsilon_x$ with center $x$ **in the metric space $(X,d)$.** Thus $B^d_{\epsilon_x}(x)=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)<\epsilon_x\}\subseteq X$ is a subset of $X$ by definition. It follows that $X$ is simply the union of all open balls in $X$.

Comment: The reason is that in case of the interval $[0, 1]$, the open ball $B^d_{\epsilon_x}(1)$ is the interval $(1-\epsilon_x, 1] \subset [0, 1]$ (provided that $\epsilon_x < 1$).

Answer (score 2):

A ball in a metric space $(X,d)$ is **by definition**:

$$B^d_\varepsilon(x) = \{y \in X: d(x,y) < \varepsilon\} \subseteq X$$

i.e. A ball is a subset of $X$, always, so in $([0,1],d), d(x,y)=|x-y|$, $B_2^d(1)=X$ and so the whole space is even a ball and so in the topology (thanks to boundedness). But we can always take any $\varepsilon=1$ for any $x$ and be OK.